# Installing Graphviz on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, installation, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm trying to install graphviz on windows 10 (Python 3.6). I went through multiple documentations but nothing seems to work. I tried to run below commands which were explained in the various documentations but it didn't work.

```
install -c anaconda graphviz 
conda install -c anaconda graphviz #I tried these commands in python console
```

I get below error:

```
Syntax Error : invalid syntax
```

Can anyone tell me the exact procedure of installing graphviz on windows?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install graphviz` didn't work for me. The library could be imported, but when I tried to open real-world examples, it crashed because of missed dependencies. (I actually found this topic while trying to solve those crashes lol).

The following two commands solved all my problems:

`conda install graphviz`

`conda install python-graphviz`

I am now able to replicate all the (graphviz) plots presented in this well-known Machine Learning repository:

https://github.com/quark0/darts

PS. Perhaps executing only the second command (alone) is enough (`conda install python-graphviz`), I am not 100% sure. I only know that `conda install graphviz` doesn't work alone for Python.

Answer (score 0):

You should first install graphviz. http://www.graphviz.org/download/
After installing it and adding to path installing the python bindings should be straight forward.

```
pip install graphviz
```

edit: Updated the link

Comment: The provided link gives an error that link could not be found. Moreover, I  found a website (http://webgraphviz.com/) where you can paste your diagraph tree code and get a graph tree so I used that to get my output as a workaround.